# What happens when more than one Coren Direbrew is involved in a Brawl?

Tags: hearthstone

Coren Direbrew says: "Always wins Brawls".

Brawl says: "Destroy all minions except one."

What happens if there's 2 (or more) of them on the field? Do they all survive, or is one of them selected at random? (Or something else?)

[image: Coren Direbrew card]

[image: Brawl card]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that when you have multiple Coren Direbrews (or Dark Iron Bouncers) on board, **one is chosen at random.**

There is a video of it happening

There is also [this page](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Dark_Iron_Bouncer#Notes) which states the same thing.

Comment: We see the active player draw, so he didn't play the last Coren Direbrews. Might be random but I think it might also be "last card played win" type of thing.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Usually in odd situations like that it's goes by order of first played, not last played.  I can only find sources calling it random.